# Unable to install virtualenvwrapper for python & django

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am new to Python and I am unable to install virtual env wrapper. I have followed the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential

sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

sudo pip install --upgrade pip

cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-org

printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s' '# virtualenv' 'export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs' \
'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

I am getting the following error here.

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Thanks,

Comment: If you run `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` what do you see?

Comment: @Chris Nothing. The command prompt is displayed again. No feedback on running the which command

Comment: @Chris  Worked. Turns out there was some problem with the pip installation.